# What exotic options are exchange-traded?

Tags: options, exotics

There are a number of exchanges that trade vanilla Call/Put American/European options on various underlyings (equities, indices, futures). There have been some trading in digital options on certain underlyings in US, but I don't see any indication that they are still traded. The ICE exchange lists some Asian APOs (Average Price Options), while both CME and The ICE list some CSOs (Calendar Spread Options) which I would also consider exotic for the purposes of this question.

What other exchange-traded exotic options do you know? Please, specify the name of the exchange and the type of the exotic options that are offered there.

Answer (score 2):

Options on the spread between crude oil and petrol are traded on the cme
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/refined-products/rbob-crack-spread-swap-futures_quotes_globex_options.html

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/refined-products/heating-oil_quotes_globex_options.html#optionProductId=566

Answer (score 0):

Callable bull/bear contracts, which are barrier options, trade on the Hong Kong exchange (HKEX). See: https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Securities/Callable-Bull-Bear-Contracts?sc_lang=en